# Excel with 3 IF conditions

Tags: excel

I am creating a template with 2 sheets in excel. Sheet 1 has the overall project status and sheet 2 has the list of projects with columns -Example B2 to H2 with Red and Green cell format.

If any of the cell in C2 to H2 is red for a particular project, then the overall project in sheet 1 is red. I used the following formula;

```
=IF(OR('Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$C$2="Red",'Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$D$2="Red",'Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$E$2="Red",'Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$F$2="Red",'Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$G$2="Red",'Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$H$2="Red"), "Red", "Green")
```

In the formula above, red is a true value and green is a false value.

So in sheet 1 the overall project status cell is highlighted in green when the  cells C2 to H2 are not highlighted in Red or Green (Cells are blank)

What is the formula to use when the cells in sheet 2 (C2 to H2) are not highlighted and the cell (overall project status) in sheet 1 is not highlighted in green. I want that cell to have a default color (White)

I am using excel 16.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: replace your current formula with a COUNTIF: `=IF(COUNTIF('Apr 6 Obeya worksheet'!$C$2:$H$2,"Red"),"Red","Green")`

Comment: Thant did not work. The cell is still green in sheet 1 when all the cells in sheet 2 are not highlighted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was giving an alternative to your Long IF.  You can't access the cell's color with a formula.  You will need vba.  There are many examples on how to do that on this site alone.

Comment: Have you thought about using conditional formatting to color the cell background? It will be very tedious to setup, but if it was me I would get it done with vba.

Comment: Yes, I did use conditional formatting to color the cell background. As far as VBA goes, not my strong suite yet. Thanks for your help Blake and Scott.

Comment: What will be the VBA code for the cell not to be filled in sheet 1 if the cells in sheet 2 are not filled with either red or green?